# LWJGL - Rotating the matrix produces an unnecessary roll

Tags: opengl, rotation, translation, lwjgl, vertex-shader

I am using LWJGL, with VAOs VBOs and GLSL Shaders to create a Block world.
I started work on the FreeFly camera and I have been having trouble.

*This is the way I am rotating my camera:*

```
    Matrix4f modelMatrix = new Matrix4f(); //ROTATION
    Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f(); //TRANSLATION

     //ROTATE
    Matrix4f.rotate(this.degreesToRadians(game.getGameDisplay().getGameCamera().roll()), new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), 
            modelMatrix, modelMatrix); //ROTATE around Z
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(game.getGameDisplay().getGameCamera().yaw()), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), 
            modelMatrix, modelMatrix); //ROTATE around Y
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(game.getGameDisplay().getGameCamera().pitch()), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), 
            modelMatrix, modelMatrix); //ROTATE around X

    // Translate camera [*-1 because For some reason the world is inverted.. ill fix this later]
    Matrix4f.translate(new Vector3f(game.getGameDisplay().getGameCamera()
            .x()*-1, game.getGameDisplay().getGameCamera()
            .y()*-1, game.getGameDisplay().getGameCamera()
            .z()*-1), viewMatrix, viewMatrix); //TRANSLATE TO X Y Z
```

*In the shaders this is how I am applying the rotation and translation:*

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix; //PROJECTION
uniform mat4 viewMatrix; //TRANSLATION
uniform mat4 modelMatrix; //ROTATION

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;
in vec3 in_TextureCoord;//NOT USED

out vec4 pass_Color;
out vec3 pass_TextureCoord;//NOT USED

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = in_Position;
    // Override gl_Position with our new calculated position
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix  * modelMatrix * viewMatrix * in_Position;

    pass_Color = in_Color;
    pass_TextureCoord = in_TextureCoord;
}
```

And this for some reason produces a slight roll when I move my mouse up and down.. the roll intensifies when I start moving around the world.

I tried not rotating around the Z axis yet I am still getting a roll which is weird. It doesn't make sense that when I comment out the rotate of the Mat4f Z axis roll one it still gives me the roll as I am never rotating it around that axis... (This is why I assume that my movement and mouse code works well and the problem lays somewhere else)

Could anyone figure out why I am getting this weird roll issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was rotating the Matrix in the WRONG ORDER.
First it needs to be PITCH only then you rotate YAW because otherwise PITCH will translate to a ROLL instead of a PITCH when your YAW value is not 0.

Answer (score -1):

OpenGl uses premultiplication to apply matrices, not post like you supposed it would. I.e. the last matrix you set is the first that will be applied.

You will have to change the order in which you apply the matrices.

Comment: To what order will I have to change it to?

Comment: I have tried every way, the way I have it right now is correct. I first do the projection then I rotate then I translate